# Getting node stack overflow error in R for Quicksort

Tags: r, stack-overflow, quicksort

```
quicksort <- function(x, s, e) {
    p = s
    i = 0
    j = 0
    for (k in 1:length(x)) {
        if (x[p] < x[k]) 
            i = k
    }
    if (!i) 
        i = e
    for (k in length(x):1) {
        if (x[p] > x[k]) 
            j = k
    }
    if (!j) 
        j = s
    if (i < j) {
        t = x[i]
        x[i] = x[j]
        x[j] = t
    } else {
        t = x[j]
        x[j] = x[p]
        x[p] = t
        quicksort(x, s, j - 1)
        quicksort(x, j + 1, e)
    }
    x
}
quick = function(x) {
    quicksort(x, 1, length(x))
}
```

When I run this i R console with a Vector I getting Error

```
> x<-c(4,47,480,15,0,147,1,56862,12)
> quick(x)
Error: node stack overflow
```

Its working when testing each command in R console but complete code doesn't work perfectly is the logic correct or wrong with code

Comment: Run through it manually a few times.  You'll notice that at some point you're making calls to quicksort with the same parameters as you entered the function with.  So if nothing changes... it's just going to end up calling quicksort(x, 1, 0) and then somewhere in the function it calls quicksort(x, 1, 0) and then somewhere in that function call it calls quicksort(x, 1, 0)...

Comment: @Dason I think problem of Infinite recursion

Answer (score 0):

Modified the Code as

```
quicksort<-function(x){
if(length(x)<=1)return(x)
p<-x[1]
therest<-x[-1]
i<-therest[therest<p]
j<-therest[therest>p]
i<-quicksort(i)
j<-quicksort(j)
return(c(i,p,j))
}
```

Now it Works The Console is responded as

```
> x<-c(4,47,480,15,0,147,1,56862,12)
> quicksort(x)
[1]     0     1     4    12    15    47   147   480 56862
```

The Code in the Question is implementation from C++ but code there in the answer is direct R